# Video tearing with KDE compositing

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, kde, tearing, kwin

I have video tearing with compositing enabled in KWin.

I have 2 monitors in twinview, VBlank is set to sync with one of them. I have some tearing on that monitor anyway, and it's much worse on the other one.

The horizontal tearing occurs everywhere on the desktop, I can see it when dragging windows and such.

I'm on 12.04 with the proprietary 302.17 drivers. VSync is enabled everywhere (in KWin and nvidia-settings). I have nvidia-settings --load-config-only in startup.

The only way I can get rid of the tearing is to disable compositing, and I don't want to do that. Compiz can run with no tearing, so should KWin.

I have tried everything, I don't know what to do anymore. I've been googling for weeks. I am at my wit's end.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Nvidia 660ti KDE 4.8 and 304 drivers.

I ran some tests with different configurations (Nvidia settings and KWin) and it is related to the **PowerMizer** settings. On adaptive, I get tearing both on desktop and video (both with VDPAU and without). On max performance, tearing is gone.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good tutorial on how to fix video tearing in Ubuntu on [OMG! Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/01/how-to-fix-video-tearing-in-videos-nvidia-ubuntu).

I hope this link can solve your question.

Comment: I cannot utilize **Compiz** Config under KDE.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1763670) could help?

Comment: I'm using KDE, **not** Compiz. Compiz is not running on my system.